# How to select and get two input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue when I select an option it will get the input value perfectly but I want to add one more input value which is email so for example,
when I select (Elvis) option & get two value phone and email in different input field.

```
<select class="name" name="name[]">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
<option value="Elvis" data-phonenumber="11111" data-email="abc@gmail.com">Elvis</option>
<option value="Frank" data-phonenumber="22222" data-email="123@gmail.com">Frank</option>
<option value="Jim" data-phonenumber="33333" data-email="123@gmail.com">Jim</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="phonenumber" name="phonenumber[]" value="" >
<input type="text" class="email" name="email[]" value="" >

<br />
<select class="name" name="name[]">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
<option value="Elvis" data-phonenumber="11111" data-email="abc@gmail.com">Elvis</option>
<option value="Frank" data-phonenumber="22222" data-email="123@gmail.com">Frank</option>
<option value="Jim" data-phonenumber="33333" data-email="123@gmail.com">Jim</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="phonenumber" name="phonenumber[]" value="" >
<input type="text" class="email" name="email[]" value="" >
<br />



here is script

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {                                       
    $('.name').live('change', function() {
$(this).next($('.phonenumber')).val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-phonenumber'));

    })
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps. I've used jquery

-edit----

code indent and added comments

```js
//body render wait
$(document).ready(function (){
    
    //loop selects with "name" class a attach change callback on each
  $('.name').each(function(idx, elem){
 
    $(elem).change(function(){
      //get selected option element
      var option = $(this).find(':selected');
      //get phone number data
      var p = $(option).data('phonenumber');
      //get email data
      var e = $(option).data('email');
      //find next phonenumber input and set value
      $(elem).parent().find('.phonenumber').val(p);
      //find next email input and set value
      $(elem).parent().find('.email').val(e);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tamplate">
  <select class="name">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Elvis" data-phonenumber="11111" data-email="abc@gmail.com">Elvis</option>
    <option value="Frank" data-phonenumber="22222" data-email="123@gmail.com">Frank</option>
    <option value="Jim" data-phonenumber="33333" data-email="123@gmail.com">Jim</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" value="" >
  <input type="text" class="email" name="email" value="" >
</div>

<div class="tamplate">
  <select class="name">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="Elvis" data-phonenumber="11111" data-email="abc@gmail.com">Elvis</option>
    <option value="Frank" data-phonenumber="22222" data-email="123@gmail.com">Frank</option>
    <option value="Jim" data-phonenumber="33333" data-email="123@gmail.com">Jim</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" value="" >
  <input type="text" class="email" name="email" value="" >
</div>
```

Comment: but i have an issue when i add div after  example </select><div class="abcd"> <input type="text" class="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" value="" ></div> it is not working can you help me

Comment: edited to find input fields no matter how deep they are. hope it helps